# Send Email with Generated PDF as attachment from Trigger

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am sending email with generated pdf as attachment from trigger as given this blog:
[Send Email with Generated PDF as attachment from Trigger](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/apex/send-email-with-generated-pdf-as-attachment-from-trigger/)

I tried to apply the logic and it is working absolutely fine for my Visualforce Page , but as soon as I give an extension to my page with a controller the functionality doesnt work.Do I have to make some changes regarding my controller?

I did same as given in blog only I added controller in my vf page.

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="Case" extensions="BankMandariPDFController"  sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" >
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
            }

               @page {
                size: letter;
                margin: 20mm;      
                }
        </style>
    </head>


    <br/>
    <br/>
   <apex:outputText style="font-size: 13px;background-color: yellow;" value="{0,date,MMMM dd, yyyy}">
      <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" />


   </apex:outputText>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <!--  
   <table style="width:80%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <apex:outputLabel >Patient Name:</apex:outputLabel>         
        </td>
        <td>


            <apex:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px;">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!acc.name}" /></apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <apex:outputLabel >Patient?s contact number:</apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
        <td>

           <apex:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px;">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!acc.phone}" /></apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <apex:outputLabel >Patient?s email address:</apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
        <td>

           <apex:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px;">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!acc.PersonEmail}" /></apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <apex:outputLabel >Patient?s Passport number:</apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
        <td>

           <apex:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px;">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!acc.NRIC_no_PP_no__c}" /></apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> 
           <apex:outputLabel >Card Holder?s Name:</apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
        <td>

           <apex:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px;">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!acc.name}" /></apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> 
           <apex:outputLabel >Mandiri Private Card number:</apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
        <td>
           Mandiri Private Card number 

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> 
           <apex:outputLabel >Mandiri Prioritas Card number :</apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
        <td>
           Mandiri Prioritas Card number 
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> 
           <apex:outputLabel >Card Holder?s Passport number:</apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
        <td>

           <apex:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px;">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!c.HidNRIC_PP_Number__c}" /></apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> 
           <apex:outputLabel >Relationship with Card Holder:</apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
        <td>

           <apex:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px;">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!c.Relationship_with_Card_Holder__c}" /></apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   -->
   <br/> 



</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class BankMandariPDFController {

 public Case c{get;set;}
 public Account Acc{get;set;}
 public Id caseId{get;set;}

 public BankMandariPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    caseId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
    //Acc =[Select Account.Name,Account.Phone,(Select Id,Card_Number__c FROM Cases) FROM Account];
    c = [Select id,AccountId,HidNRIC_PP_Number__c,Relationship_with_Card_Holder__c,Account.Name,Account.phone,Account.PersonEmail,Account.NRIC_no_PP_no__c from case where id=:caseId limit 1];
    acc = [Select Id, Name,Phone,PersonEmail,NRIC_no_PP_no__c  From Account Where Id =: c.AccountId];

 }

}
```

Creating APEX based REST API with POST Method :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/sendPDFEmail/*')

    Global class GETPDFContent{
         @HttpPost

        global static void sendEmail(String EmailIdCSV, String Subject, String body) {

        List<String> EmailIds = EmailIdCSV.split(',');

            PageReference ref = Page.BankMandariPDF;
            Blob b = ref.getContentAsPDF();

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            efa1.setFileName('BankMandariPDF.pdf');
            efa1.setBody(b);
            String addresses;
            email.setSubject( Subject +String.valueOf(DateTime.now()));
            email.setToAddresses( EmailIds  );
            email.setPlainTextBody(Body);
            email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa1});
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

        }
    }
```

We will be consuming rest api.

```
public class SendVFAsAttachment{

 @future(callout=true)

    public static void sendVF(String EmailIdCSV, String Subject,String body,String userSessionId)
    {
        //Replace below URL with your Salesforce instance host

        String addr = 'https://cs18.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/sendPDFEmail';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint( addr );
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + userSessionId);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

        Map<String,String> postBody = new Map<String,String>();
        postBody.put('EmailIdCSV',EmailIdCSV);
        postBody.put('Subject',Subject);
        postBody.put('body',body);
        String reqBody = JSON.serialize(postBody);

        req.setBody(reqBody);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
    }
}
```

Wrote a trigger

```
trigger SendPDFAttachment on Case (before insert) {
         SendVFAsAttachment.sendVF('sk2908@gmail.com','Bank Customers Referral',

    'Bank Customers Referral',UserInfo.getSessionId());

}
```

Comment: It will be helpful to find the issue if you post the code that you have developed. :)

Comment: Hello manjit I added all code.

Comment: This code looks fine. I believe you have added your your instance URL in remote sites. Can you post the VF page markup as well. Also is there a specific error you receive? If yes please post it as well.

Comment: I added my visualforce page also and adding instance URL in remote sites.

Comment: I see that you have added a Standard controller `Case` in you VF page, A Standard Controller requires a record Id to work with. Since you are invoking the page through a rest call, Also in you `BankMandariPDFController ` you are trying to get an Id and since you are. Can you try adding ref.getParameters().put('id', 'someCaseIdhere'); after this line PageReference ref = Page.BankMandariPDF; and then call you getcontent method. You will be required to pass one more parameter from you trigger to your rest service i.e. ID from one of the records.

Comment: Didnt get what actually you are trying to convey through your comment here,If you can paste the edited code here it will be of great help.